# React native Lock app to landscape issue

Tags: orientation, react-native

I had locked my react application to landscape by adding the following code to Application tag(in Manifest) and inside every activities tag

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize
```

It was working fine, until i added the modules for file reading react-native-fs

Now when the app starts the screen is rotated to landscape, but if the user rotates the phone to portrait, the screen also rotates to portrait (it should remain in landscape instead).

**Things i tried**

- Added android:screenOrientation="landscape" in the manifest of modules.
- In MainApplication registered *registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks*  and added activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); in onActivityCreated.

Still it's not locked to landscape.

The app should be locked to landscape even if rotated to portrait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The React-Native-Navigation library was causing the issue. 
It had a class **ActivityCallBacks** inside **Controller** package . Adding the following code inside *onActivityCreated()* resolved the issue :

```
 activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but I think you need to use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: I have that tag already. I thought it was the problem, but i was able to figure out the issue , i have posted the answer.